# multilevel threads takes time

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp

I have created a module to transfer the data using multiple sockets using TCP client server communication. This transfers the file of 20MB in 10 secs.

Multiple sockets sends/receives the data in each of their a separate thread.

When I launch the module from another worker thread the time taken to send the same file increases to 40 secs.

Please let me know any solutions to avoid the time lagging.

Comment: Show code, specify what threading library you use, etc. And most importantly, just how many threads are we talking here? And running with how many CPU cores?

Answer (score 0):

Are you synchronizing the threads to read the content from the file at Client side and write back to file at server side? This adds time.

Along with this, by default you will having context switching time between multiple threads at both client and server.

Comment: The context switching is taking time more than 200ms when called from a thread. But when the module is called from main thread the context switching is max as 16msec. Is there any possible way to reduce this time?

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be disk caching and seeking. If you are not already doing this, try interleaving blocks transferred by different threads more finely (like, say, to 4KB, so bytes 0...4095 transferred by 1st thread, 4096...8191 by 2nd thread, etc).

Also avoid mutexes, for example by having each thread know what it's supposed to read and send, or write and receive, when thread starts, so no inter-thread communication is needed. Aborting the whole transfer can be done by an *atomic* flag variable (checked by each thread after transferring a block) instead of mutexes.

Also on receiving end, make sure to do buffering in memory, so that you write to destination file sequentially. That is, if one thread transfers blocks faster than some other, those "early" blocks are just kept in memory until all the preceding blocks have been received and written.

If buffer size becomes an issue here, you may need to implement some inter-thread synchronization at one end (doesn't matter much, wether you slow down receiving or sending), to prevent the fastest thread getting too far ahead of the slowest thread, but for file sizes in the order of tens of megabytes, on PCs, this should not become an issue.

Comment: I am reading a file into multiple buffers using each thread. And on receiving end the data is again maintained in the buffer to sort in a proper order.